# New Line After Each PHPUnit Test

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-5

I've got a test suite setup on a Laravel project which uses PHPUnit. Usually the dots which indicate whether the test has passed or not are shown on the same line, however in this project each dot is separated with a new line:

[image]

I've searched through all my tests to see if something is echoing an `\n` or a `PHP_EOL` but can't see anything, I've tried different versions of PHPUnit and I've tried starting over with a totally new test suite. None of these attempts have fixed the problem! The configuration in `phpunit.xml` for this test suite is identical to other projects too.

Can anyone suggest anything else I could do to fix this?

Comment: It happens for me too, looks like a bug in PHPStorm : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-46964

Comment: This was due to an accidental new line before `<?php` in one of my Laravel config files in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it was a space before the opening `<?php` tag in one of my files.

Answer (score 2):

The output can come from the actual `php` files being tested. Aside from obvious `echo` sentences that can be executed during the test, it can be caused by files with the closing `?>` tag that have a newline character afterwards. If this is the case I'd suggest getting rid of the closing `?>` tags as they bring nothing useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - forgot to add `?>` to the things I'd searched for and there are no occurrences :(

Comment: try to execute each test separately and check when this occurs, so you can narrow the problem source.

Comment: It's happening on every test! I've tried replacing my `TestCase` class with a brand new one from a fresh Laravel install. Done a search in all my app files to see if something is getting `echo`ed out or similar but no luck.

Comment: Did you have any luck with yours?